# Will being diagnosed with ADHD make getting a UK Visa a lot harder?

Tags: uk-visa, medical

I want to permanently move over to the UK in 6-12 months from New Zealand.

I don't really know if I'm going to go for the skills shortage visa, or 2 year youth mobility scheme visa.

I have heard that medical issues are the biggest problem for people getting a visa, even if they're applying for a job on the skills shortage list.

Will being diagnosed as having [ADHD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention_deficit_hyperactivity_disorder) make it really difficult to get a visa to live and work in the UK?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘the normal visa’?

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while since I last looked at UK Visa's. The one I vaguely recall doesn't seem to exist anymore. I will update the question.

Comment: Perhaps what you have heard about medical issues being a problem getting a visa could be due potential drain on medical resources, which may not be an issue for something like ADHD (as opposed to someone with, say, heart disease)

Comment: @Midavalo I don't know the treatment protocol for ADHD that prevails in the UK, but any medical services are a drain on the system.  That an ADHD patient may be likely to be a lesser drain on those resources than a heart patient does not seem to be relevant.  At least, I have never seen anything to that effect in UK immigration law, but I certainly may have overlooked it.